# Menger's theorem with restrictions on where the paths can begin and end

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, combinatorial-optimization, graph-minors

Let $k\in\mathbb N$. Given a finite graph with two subsets of vertices $X$ and $Y$, Menger's Theorem gives a criterion for when there are $k$ pairwise disjoint paths starting in $X$ and ending in $Y$.

Now let $X_1$, $Y_1$, $\dots$,$X_k$, $Y_k$ be subsets of vertices. Is there a "similar" condition for when there are $k$ pairwise disjoint paths, one path starting in $X_1$ and ending in $Y_1$, a second path starting in $X_2$ and ending in $Y_2$, $\dots$, and a $k^{\text {th}}$ path starting in $X_k$ and ending in $Y_k$?

Comment: Perhaps, if you copied M's theorem here (into your "Question"), there'd be a better chance to get an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no known necessary and sufficient condition like in Menger's theorem.

However, there is a polynomial-time algorithm that decides if the paths exist.  This is one of the main results of the Graph Minors Project of Robertson and Seymour (see [Graph Minors XIII](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0095895685710064)).  The algorithm is quite involved and uses many of the results from the graph minors series.  Robertson and Seymour solve the problem when each $X_i$ and $Y_i$ have size $1$, but your problem can be reduced to this case by shrinking each $X_i$ and each $Y_i$ to a single vertex.

The $k=2$ case (with $|X_1|=|X_2|=|Y_1|=|Y_2|=1$) has a nice necessary and sufficient condition for $4$-connected graphs.  The required paths do not exist if and only if $G$ is planar and $X_1, X_2, Y_1, Y_2$ occur in this cyclic order on the outerface of $G$. This was proved independently by Thomassen and Seymour.

No necessary and sufficient conditions are known for $k \geq 3$.

Comment: A nice answer (+1). ######### The meaning of word *condition* has to be narrowed down before the OP's question makes any sense.

Comment: @Tony Huynh: Thank you.